# I'm retrieving data from Firebase and storing it in an object, but then when I try to log it to the console it's showing undefined... why?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

So I'm trying to retrieve the URLs for three images from the database, then store them in an object like this:

```
let pics = {
  zero: "url0.jpg",
  one: "url1.jpg",
  two: "url2.jpg"
}
```

So I can then transfer them to an array in a specific order like so:

```
let picsArray = [pics.zero, pics.one, pics.two]
```

However, the following code is giving a bizarre result in the console...

```
let currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser
let pics = {}
firebase.storage().ref(currentUser.uid).listAll().then(results => {
  results.items.forEach(async imageRef => {
    let meta = await imageRef.getMetadata()
    let order = meta.customMetadata.order
    let url = await imageRef.getDownloadURL()
    pics[order] = url
  })
  console.log(pics)
  console.log(pics.zero)
  console.log(pics.one)
  console.log(pics.two)
}).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

...displaying the correct object as expected from the first console.log, but then displaying 'undefined' for each of the following three. How is this even possible, given the object was recognised and logged on literally the previous line?

Comment: console log (typeof pics.zero) etc to see what is being returned.

Comment: Just says undefined again

Comment: What is the output of console.log(pics)?

Comment: {}
one: "url1.jpg"
zero: "url0.jpg"
__proto__: Object

Comment: That seems like a promise object.